# DroboApps share not accessible

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, drobo, drobo-fs

My Drobo-FS is version 2.1.2 (latest) and so is Drobo Dashboard. I have a few shares which I can access without any problem.

When trying to enable the DroboApps share (and install some), I can't access the share from my Windows XP machine. It asks for user and password but fails every time.

When marking the "connect to" on the Dashboard, it says "connected". `net use` doesn't show anything related to that share.

All other shares are connected and OK. I tried accessing it from my hosted XP (on Ubuntu 11.10 64bit, VirtualBox) and no problem at all.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing `net view` I noticed that the working share is marked as used by "UNC" (whatever that means...) and trying to connect to the DroboApps from net use spitted out something about only one user per share/server. So I deleted the working share `net use x: /delete`, logged out and then tried to connect to my DroboApps share - Voila. Of course all other users were logged out (just in case).

Answer (score -1):

For the "one user / share" thing, what I do is add the IP of my Drobo to the hosts file and give it multiple names.  In my case, it's name is "Zipper"

Hosts file looks like:
192.168.2.150     ZIPPER2
192.168.2.150     ZIPPER3
192.168.2.150     ZIPPER4

Then I can connect to \zipper2\someshare on X: and \zipper3\othershare on Y: